# How to read string to an array and get values from the array

Tags: bash

Currently I have

```
DATE_LIST=$(cat "$OUT_FILE" | xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//*[local-name()='entry']//*[local-name()='$start_position_date'][@name='beginposition']" -v '.' -n)
```

The result is something like:

```
DATE_LIST= 2015-10-10
2015-11-11
```

... and so on

```
IFS='\n' read -a array <<< "$DATE_LIST"

echo "${array[0]}" //I get the first one
echo "${array[1]}" //I get nothing
```

How to parse it correctly? `DATE_LIST` is generated from xml and strings are separated with `\n`.

Comment: If each element of `DATE_LIST` is guaranteed free of whitespace, you can populate the array directly with `array=( $(xmlstartlet ... < "$OUT_FILE"))`.

Comment: Also, you need `IFS=$'\n'` to set `IFS` to an actual newline character.

Comment: The first solution works, thanks!

And in response to the second comment adding $ does not affect the outcome `IFS=$'\n' read -a array <<< "$DATE_LIST"`

Comment: @user3960875 using `IFS='\n'` is not right even if it doesn't affect the outcome. `'\n'` is just a string literally `\n` not a newline.

Answer (score 0):

This appends each line from the output into an array, supporting lines with
withespaces.

```
array=()
IFS='
'
for line in $(cat "$OUT_FILE" | xmlstarlet set -T ...)
do
    array+=("$line")
done
unset IFS
```